# ajax load an external file by passing parameters

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Am trying to load an external file to a div using this function

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#postdiv").load('posts.php');
       });
```

This is working alright.

The problem is, I need to pass parameters/variables to posts.php from the caller page and use them to do some filtering.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ajax

ajax  is better option,best practice.

```
  var value = "value of the data here";  
    $.ajax({
      url: "posts.php",
      data: "key="+value,
      type: "post",
      success: function(data){
            $('#postdiv').html(data);
      }
    });
```

Comment: this is possible with `.load` function.

Comment: both are possible ,but ajax  is better option,best practice.

Comment: Both methods are working. But I've opted for the jquery. Thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

You can pass parameters with jquery `load`

This method will pass parameter as `POST`

```
$("#postdiv").load('posts.php',{'name' : 'Test','age' : 25});
```

if you want pass it as `GET` you can do like this

```
$("#postdiv").load('posts.php?name=Test&age=25');
```

you can read more [here](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

you can make an ajax call

```
$.ajax({
      url: "posts.php",
      data: data,
      type: "post",
      success: function(data){
            $('#postdiv').html(data);
      }
    });
```

or you want to go for load then try below code

```
$( "#postdiv" ).load( "posts.php", { "test[]": [ "test1", "test2" ] } );
```